# WCF Data Services 5.0 SDK Samples

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services

Downloaded and installed the WCF Data Services 5.0 from

[WCF Data Services 5.0 for OData V3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29306)

According to the link below it is supposed to include some code samples.  But I cannot find the code samples.  Does anyone know if there really are code samples and if so where?  I am looking for code sample for Data Service Provider.

[www.odata.org/developers](http://www.odata.org/developers)

What may be the case is the code samples are in a prior version.  If someone knows the latest version with Data Service Provider code samples please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample of the untyped custom provider is part of the OData Provider Toolkit: http://www.odata.org/ecosystem#samplecode

Comment: Thanks, the SDK sample code and blog are very informative.  Neither use SQL as the underlying custom (non EF) store.  The blog mentions using SQL.  You don't happen to know of any sample code using SQL as a custom (non EF) provider?

Comment: We don't have a SQL backed custom provider. Mainly because it's either very stupid (just a wrapper around something like LINQ to SQL), or VERY complex (custom implementation of IQueryable over SQL).

Comment: Don't understand the use of "we", "stupid", or "VERY complex".  The blog specifically mentions "translate expression to SQL" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/03/02/creating-a-data-service-provider-part-9-un-typed.aspx   If the only intended use of custom data data provider is List<Dictionary<string,object>> it is  limited to in memory data.  Again, thank you for you help.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Custom provider is definitely not limited to in-memory stores. It just requires an implementation of IQueryable over the store in question (in your case SQL DB). The only sample of how to build IQueryable over SQL DB I know of is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx.

Comment: The above blog address SQL store but does not deal with untyped.  Another you pointed me in another question deals with untyped but does not deal with SQL backend.  Hopefully I can figure out how to merge the two.

Comment: As I said above, untyped SQL provider is hard. I'm not aware of a publicly available source for any such provider. And those which do exist are usually very specific to the SQL DB at hand, so not generic providers in that sense.

Comment: Understand.  I don't need a response.  It was just a comment for someone following.  And I am not looking for a generic MSSQL provider (via EF can basically do that).  Understand I will need to convert the expression to TSQL and .NET and implement iQueryable.   What I want to expose as ODATA is dynamic and in SQL but lots of formatting before it gets to the consumer.   Thanks again.